# How to reference Text to respective email address using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

so I have set up an emailing system in which emails are sent out to people that own a specific item that have a due date coming up. There are at least 1,000 items on my excel sheet and each item has a specific owner. However the owners are labeled using an ID. The ID refers to an email address in another sheet called "Permissions" . My email function works, however I am having trouble with my recepients. I am not able to match the ID on the sheet that has the items to the email address in the other sheet. I am fairly new to VBA so please excuse my code. I am still learning. Thank you!

The worksheet name "Register" is the worksheet with all of the items and due dates.

Code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestEmailer()

Dim Row        As Long
Dim lstRow      As Long

Dim Message As Variant
Dim Frequency As String 'Cal Frequency
Dim DueDate As Date 'Due Date for Calibration
Dim vbCrLf As String 'For HTML formatting
Dim registerkeynumber As String 'Register Key Number
Dim class As Variant 'Class
Dim owner As String ' Owner
Dim status As String 'Status
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim toList As Variant
Dim Ebody As String
Dim esubject As String
Dim Filter As String
Dim LQAC As String


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True

End With

Set ws = Sheets(1)
ws.Select

lstRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(2, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, Range("CalDueDate").Column).End(xlUp).Row)


For Row = 2 To lstRow


DueDate = CDate(Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, Range("DueDate").Column).Value) 'DUE DATE




registerkeynumber = Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, Range("RegisterKey").Column).Value

class = Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, Range("Class").Column).Value


status = Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, Range("Status").Column).Value

LQAC = Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, Range("LQAC").Column).Value

Filter = Worksheets("Permissions").Cells(Row, Worksheets("Permissions").Range("MailFilter").Column).Value


If DueDate - Date <= 7 And class > 1 And status = "In Service" And DueDate <> "12:00:00 AM" Then

vbCrLf = "<br><br>"

'THIS IS WHERE I AM NOT SURE IF I AM REFERENCING CORRECTLY.  I AM NOT SURE HOW TO REFERENCE THE ID FROM THE 'REGISTER' AND MATCH IT WITH THE EMAIL ADDRESS IN THE 'PERMISSIONS' WORKSHEET. AS OF NOW I AM ONLY REFERENCING THE EMAIL ADDRESS BUT THEY ARE NOT MATCHING UP.

toList = Worksheets("Permissions").Cells(Row, Worksheets("Permissions").Range("Email").Column).Value                                                   'RECEPIENT OF EMIAL


esubject = "TEXT " & Cells(Row, Range("Equipment").Column).Value & " is due in the month of " & Format(DueDate, "mmmm-yyyy")


        Ebody = "<HTML><BODY>"
        Ebody = Ebody & "Dear " & Cells(Row, Range("LQAC").Column).Value & vbCrLf
        Ebody = Ebody & "</BODY></HTML>"





SendEmail Bdy:=Ebody, Subjct:=esubject, Two:=toList





End If

Next Row

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True

End With


End Sub

Function SendEmail(Bdy As Variant, Subjct As Variant, Optional Two As Variant = "Email@xxx", Optional ReplyTo As Variant = "Email@xxx", Optional Carbon As Variant = "Email@xxx", Optional Attch As Variant = "FilePath", Optional Review As Boolean = False)
    Dim OutlookEM As Outlook.Application
    Dim EMItem As MailItem



         If Not EmailActive Then Exit Function


        If Two = "Email@xxx" Then
            MsgBox "There is no Address to send this Email"
            Two = ""
            Review = True
            'Exit Function
        End If
        'Create Outlook object
         Set OutlookEM = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

         'Create Mail Item
         Set EMItem = OutlookEM.CreateItem(0)

        With EMItem
            .To = Two
            .Subject = Subjct
            .HTMLBody = Bdy

        End With
        If ReplyTo <> "Email@xxx" Then EMItem.ReplyRecipients.Add ReplyTo
        If Attch <> "FilePath" Then EMItem.Attachments.Add Attch
        If Carbon <> "Email@xxx" Then EMItem.CC = Carbon
        If Review = True Then
            EMItem.Display (True)
        Else
            EMItem.Display
           ' EMItem.Send
        End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I am able to follow what the issue is here.  It doesn't look like your code is using any vlookup formula or matching formula to find the email.  Unless they are on the same row between the different sheets, you will need to find the value.

VBA has the ability to use the functions that you would normally use in Excel.

If you tweek the code below with the correct range and column number, you should be able to find the correct email address based on an ID.

```
' instead of 1 below, use the column for the id to look up
lookupValue = Worksheets("Register").Cells(Row, 1).Value

' range of the ids and emails in the permissions table - edit whatever the range should be
Rng = Worksheets("Permissions").Range("A1:B100")

' column to look up - number of columns between the id and email in the permissions tab
col = 2

' whether you want excel to try to find like match for the lookup value
' pretty much never have this be true if you want to have confidence in the result
likeMatch = False

emailAddress = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupValue, Rng, col, likeMatch)
```